# Any isomorphism $f: x \rightarrow x$ in a category has to be the identity morphism?

Tags: category-theory

Let $C$ be a category and $f: x \rightarrow x$ be an isomorphism. Is it true that $f$ must be $id_x$? If no, what would be a good counterexample?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $C=\mathcal{Set}$, the category of sets, and $x=\{a,b\}$ then we have two isomorphisms $\{a,b\}\to\{a,b\},$ one the identity and one which swaps $a,b.$

In general, in $\mathcal{Set},$ the isomorphisms $x\to x$ are the permutations of the set $x.$

Answer (score 3):

No. See, for instance, the category of vector spaces over some field $k$. And almost any category of common usage in algebra/geometry.

Comment: Thanks so much, really.

Answer (score 1):

No. A single group is a category with one object and right multiplication by an element is a morphism $x \to x$.

You can visualize a group as a daisy with all the elements as petals looping back to the floral disc.

Comment: How do you propose you compose arrows with this description?

Comment: $x \mapsto ax$ where $a$ is an element of the group's underlying set. The composition of two arrows $a, b$ is $x \mapsto abx$ which is $x \mapsto cx$.

Comment: I mean, you could make it work (just take function composition). What I was trying to point out is that it is usually easier to think of the arrows in your category as just the *elements* of the group. Then composition of arrows is just the group multiplication.

Comment: Well relationship between morphism and concrete underlying set is difficult for a newbie to grok.